# iMac won’t boot disk full error

Tags: imac, startup

We have a 2011 iMac that has many precious photos/videos that we’re hoping to not lose.

When trying to start it, the Apple symbol displays for about 2 minutes and the progress bar makes it about 80% across, then it just shuts off.

After researching it a bit, tried Verbose mode. Here are the messages it displays right before it shuts off:

*Checking extended attributes file*

*Invalid index key*

*Rebuilding extended attributes B-tree*

*Disk full error*

[image]*The volume Macintosh HD could not be repaired*

I’ve logged in with single user mode, remounted the disk to allow for deletion and removed about 5 gigs worth of files.

Rebooted, but getting the same error messages. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If you boot in Recovery Mode (cmd+r) can you from the terminal (top menu /utilities/terminal) access your files? If yes and if you have an external disk, you can save your data.

Comment: Can you access it using another machine in Target Disk mode. Then copy all the data. Do a rebuild and plan backups for the future.